# DhtmlX tree pagination

Tags: tree, pagination, dhtmlx

below is my function problem is pagination is not working if i remove tree from all_cases.setColTypes("tree,ch,ro,ro,ro,link,ro,link,link"); or i replace tree with link or ro or ch then pagination works but i need pagination with tree any body help me please what's the mistake is or where i m wrong.
function loadAllCasesForOrthocaps(){

```
all_cases = new dhtmlXGridObject("simorth_cases");
all_cases.setSkin('dhx_terrace');
all_cases.setImagePath(basepath+"common/js/imgs/");
all_cases.setColSorting("int,int,str,str,str,int,str,int,str");
all_cases.setHeader("S.No,,Case ID,Clinician Name,Patient Name,Progress,Case Date,Status, View");
all_cases.setInitWidths("100,50,90,180,140,140,175,200,*");
all_cases.setColTypes("tree,ch,ro,ro,ro,link,ro,link,link");
all_cases.enableMultiline(true);
all_cases.setColumnMinWidth(50, 0);

all_cases.attachEvent("onBeforeSorting", customOrthoColumnSort);
all_cases.setColSorting("str,na,server,server,server,server,server,na,na");

all_cases.enablePaging(true, 100, 100, "pagingArea");
all_cases.setPagingSkin("toolbar", "dhx_terrace");

all_cases.attachEvent("onXLS", function() {
    document.getElementById('cover').style.display = 'block';
});
all_cases.attachEvent("onXLE", function() {
    document.getElementById('cover').style.display = 'none';
});
all_cases.init();
all_cases.loadXML(basepath+'orguser/loadOrthoCases');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the issue cannot be reproduced locally. Please, refer to the following sample:  http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeGrid/samples/02_loading_big_datasets/01_treegrid_paging.html

Paging with the treegrid works well in it. After setting the terrace skin and a toolbar paging it also works well.
If the problem still occurs for you may contact official dhtmlx support and share with a demo link where the problem can be reconstructed or provide a complete demo where the issue can be reproduced locally.